# Interface implimenttaion of the class issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

Here is the my simple senario.
I have a class(BLL class) which implemented an interface. What I wanna do is, inside the presantation layer, i want users reach only the interface and interacting the class with this interface, not the class function directly. Is there anyway to do that?

My BLL class implemeted interface :

```
    public interface IOfis
    {

        bool Add(Ofis ofs);
        bool Update(Ofis ofs);


    }

    public class BLL_Ofis:IOfis
    {
        public bool Update(Ofis ofs)
        {
            DAL_Ofis ofs_dal = new DAL_Ofis();
            try
            {
                return ofs_dal.Update(ofs);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally { ofs_dal = null; }
        }

      public bool Add(Ofis ofs_obj)
        {
            DAL_Ofis ofs_dal = new DAL_Ofis();
            try
            {
                return ofs_dal.Add(ofs_obj);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally { ofs_dal = null; }
        }
}
```

Inside the presantatoin layer, i use it like this :

```
IOfis bll_ofis = new BLL_Ofis();
bll_ofis.Update();
```

But in this situation I can also reach the class directly like this :

```
 BLL_Ofis bll_ofis = new BLL_Ofis();
 bll_ofis.Update();
```

which I dont want that.
I wanna reach only method which declared inside the Interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would want it, but a "solution" could be to change the `public` methods into explicit interface implementations. To do that, remove access modifiers (here `public`) and prepend `IOfis.` to the name of the method. Like this:

```
public class BLL_Ofis : IOfis
{
    bool IOfis.Update(Ofis ofs)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

An [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) can only be invkoked when the compile-time type of the variable is the interface type.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the method `Add` in your class as well. As for visibility, remove `public` from the class declaration, that will make it visible only for code that resides in the same assembly.

Comment: but they are inside the different dll ,that means different assembly

Comment: I mean presantation layer and BLL as being different class library

Comment: in that case the methods will only be accessible through the public interface, which, I presume, is the desired functionality